# APS Model Derivative API credit usage

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I am creating a viewer application, where in the models (all .stp files generated from Inventor assembly files) to be viewed will be periodically updated. The updated models will be uploaded to the APS bucket via an automated program with the same file names.

I have a few questions regarding the credit costs for the below operations:

1. If a model that is uploaded has no geometric differences with a file that is already translated under the same name, will there be any cloud credits used when the translation is initiated?
2. Is the rate for translation 0.1 credits for any file size? (largest expected file size is 500 mb, with most files in the range of 30 to 100 mb)

Answer (score 0):

> If a model that is uploaded has no geometric differences with a file that is already translated under the same name, will there be any cloud credits used when the translation is initiated?

This is not something the platform can do for you. When you overwrite an existing STP design in a Data Management bucket with another design, the Model Derivative service only sees the new file, and therefore it cannot determine whether the design has changed or not.

However, you *can* build this kind of optimization into your APS application. When your app receives a new set of STP files, it could first compare them with the existing designs (for example, using a hash code generated from file contents), and if it determines that the files are the same, it could skip the upload and translation process, saving some of the Model Derivative cost.

> Is the rate for translation 0.1 credits for any file size? (largest expected file size is 500 mb, with most files in the range of 30 to 100 mb)

Correct, the translation cost does not depend on the file size.